# RDS Aurora 5.6 died (randomly?)

Tags: amazon-rds, aurora

**Aurora MySQL 5.6.10a**

I can see these events in the console:

```
February 20, 2018 at 4:27:24 PM UTC+11  <server>-production DB instance restarted
February 20, 2018 at 4:26:52 PM UTC+11  <server>-production Error restarting mysql: Engine bootstrap failed with no mysqld process running...
February 20, 2018 at 4:25:31 PM UTC+11  <server>-production Recovery of the DB instance is complete.
February 20, 2018 at 4:24:27 PM UTC+11  <server>-production Error restarting mysql: Could not verify and start mysqld.
February 20, 2018 at 4:19:36 PM UTC+11  <server>-production Recovery of the DB instance has started. Recovery time will vary with the amount of data to be recovered.
```

The only errors I found in the logs are the following, but I have no idea what they are telling me:

```
2018-02-20 05:25:11 9281 [Warning] Although a path was specified for the --slow-query-log-file option, log tables are used. To enable logging to files use the --log-output=file option.
2018-02-20 05:25:28 9816 [Warning] Although a path was specified for the --slow-query-log-file option, log tables are used. To enable logging to files use the --log-output=file option.
/etc/rds/oscar-start-cmd: line 39: 9816 Killed /rdsdbbin/oscar/bin/mysqld --core-file --innodb_shared_buffer_pool_uses_huge_pages='1' "$@"
2018-02-20 05:25:39 10408 [Warning] Although a path was specified for the --slow-query-log-file option, log tables are used. To enable logging to files use the --log-output=file option.
/etc/rds/oscar-start-cmd: line 39: 10408 Killed /rdsdbbin/oscar/bin/mysqld --core-file --innodb_shared_buffer_pool_uses_huge_pages='1' "$@"
2018-02-20 05:25:51 10896 [Warning] Although a path was specified for the --slow-query-log-file option, log tables are used. To enable logging to files use the --log-output=file option.
/etc/rds/oscar-start-cmd: line 39: 10896 Killed /rdsdbbin/oscar/bin/mysqld --core-file --innodb_shared_buffer_pool_uses_huge_pages='1' "$@"
2018-02-20 05:26:07 11455 [Warning] Although a path was specified for the --slow-query-log-file option, log tables are used. To enable logging to files use the --log-output=file option.
/etc/rds/oscar-start-cmd: line 39: 11455 Killed /rdsdbbin/oscar/bin/mysqld --core-file --innodb_shared_buffer_pool_uses_huge_pages='1' "$@"
2018-02-20 05:26:24 12005 [Warning] Although a path was specified for the --slow-query-log-file option, log tables are used. To enable logging to files use the --log-output=file option.
/etc/rds/oscar-start-cmd: line 39: 12005 Killed /rdsdbbin/oscar/bin/mysqld --core-file --innodb_shared_buffer_pool_uses_huge_pages='1' "$@"
2018-02-20 05:26:35 12466 [Warning] Although a path was specified for the --slow-query-log-file option, log tables are used. To enable logging to files use the --log-output=file option.
/etc/rds/oscar-start-cmd: line 39: 12466 Killed /rdsdbbin/oscar/bin/mysqld --core-file --innodb_shared_buffer_pool_uses_huge_pages='1' "$@"
2018-02-20 05:26:53 13170 [Warning] Although a path was specified for the --slow-query-log-file option, log tables are used. To enable logging to files use the --log-output=file option.
/etc/rds/oscar-start-cmd: line 39: 13170 Killed /rdsdbbin/oscar/bin/mysqld --core-file --innodb_shared_buffer_pool_uses_huge_pages='1' "$@"
2018-02-20 05:27:05 13644 [Warning] Although a path was specified for the --slow-query-log-file option, log tables are used. To enable logging to files use the --log-output=file option.
/etc/rds/oscar-start-cmd: line 39: 13644 Killed /rdsdbbin/oscar/bin/mysqld --core-file --innodb_shared_buffer_pool_uses_huge_pages='1' "$@"
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
Displaying ~ 1000 lines of error/mysql-error-running.log.2018-02-20.05
Refresh LogClose
```

It came back up again automatically after ~15mins, but it would be nice to know what actually went wrong. CPU and memory graphs look fine.

Comment: Did you find out what the problem was?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't. It didn't happen again so far. Expecting the issue to be on AWS side.

Comment: Ok, we went for a mysql 5.7 instance instead of Aurora when Aurora didn't feel that stable.